# How to assign max-tag value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

If I assign `max-tags="1"`, it working perfectly but when I tried to assign dynamically by using `max-tags="maxtag()"`,through link function, but it is showing red border for input box. From view I am trying to put max number of tags. Everything is working fine, but input box is red, 
It is showing like following text image. Like warning. How to fixed it. 
[image]

**Working Demo**

http://plnkr.co/edit/ooTucE4yqmLwMH9kNkO7?p=preview

```
<tags-input ng-model="modeldisplay" class="input-md" display-
property="data" on-tag-removed="removedCustomerTag()"
  placeholder="Select a User" on-tag-adding="addSearchedTag()" on-tag-added="tagAdded($tag)"
  enable-editing-last-tag="removedCustomerTag()" replace-spaces-with-dashes="false" max-tags="maxtag()"
  add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
  <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" min-length="1" load-on-focus="true" load-on-empty="true" 
    max-results-to-show="10"  template="autocomplete.html">
  </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Comment: I don't know why people try down vote question without understanding it. I tried to put everything so that my question be clear..

Comment: `=` is for two-way data binding. It means, that `max-tags=""` expects scope's property. Not a result of a function like `maxtag()` or number `5`. Your code is invalid and console contains details

Comment: @goliney ,I change according to you but still it showing warning red input box...

Comment: Binding this to a function is WRONG. You should bind it to a property

Comment: @AlonEitan, I didn't get you, please see demo, http://plnkr.co/edit/ooTucE4yqmLwMH9kNkO7?p=preview

Comment: @geeks Yes, sorry. Don't understand this module (tags input) - Why it reads the property from the directive definition (`<my-directive  ... maxtag="3" ...`) instead of the template. Looks like a bug in the module itself

Comment: @AlonEitan Reason it that I want to assign dynamically so that I put inside `<my-directive `, Some other where I can use different max-tab. Thats why..

Comment: @geeks I agree that your attempt should work, but I think the problem is with the author of the module, and not on your side. I would open a ticket about this issue on the git repository of that module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most options of ngTagsInput are simply DOM attributes, thus you should use interpolation in order to dynamically change them:

```
<tags-input ng-model="modeldisplay" max-tags="{{maxtag}}" ...></tags-input>
```

That would work, but not quite as one might expect. To keep the number of watches as low as possible, ngTagsInput doesn't actively monitor DOM attributes by default, so the `{{maxtags}}` expression above is evaluated only once. In your case, that seems to be enough. But if it isn't, you can change that behavior by using the `tagsInputConfigProvider` service in your module`s config block:

```
app.config(function(tagsInputConfigProvider) {
  tagsInputConfigProvider.setActiveInterpolation('tagsInput', { 
    maxTags: true 
  });
});
```

You can learn more about that on [ngTagsInput documentation](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/global-configuration).

Finally, [here is your updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QqXv89PHuVSEamYHgokE?p=preview).

Comment: Is there any way to send parameters to the config function? In my particular case, I created an angular component with an ngTagsInput inside. I want to send as a binding in the component the default values for the ngTagsInput. I was thinking on sending that binding to the config of the component, but have not succeed with that. How can I achive this?